# error while executing command "hadoop namenode -format " from masternode?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I have configured hadoop(multi-node setup). Now before starting hadoop i want to format namenode for this i run the below command -->>

```
hadoop namenode -format
```

It gives an error which is-->

```
/home/sandip/project/hadoop-1.1.2/bin/hadoop: line 320: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-  
i386/jre/bin/java/bin/java: Not a directory
/home/sandip/project/hadoop-1.1.2/bin/hadoop: line 390: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-    
i386/jre/bin/java/bin/java: Not a directory
/home/sandip/project/hadoop-1.1.2/bin/hadoop: line 390: exec: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-   
i386/jre/bin/java/bin/java: cannot execute: Not a directory
```

plz tell me how should i resolve it ?

Comment: Looks like environment variables aren't set correctly.  Check `JAVA_HOME`.

Comment: but when i run command "javac -version" it gives javac 1.6.0_27 it means java is configured and installed on my system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ooh! i fixed it i had mistake in configuring JAVA_HOME in hadoop-env.sh now i corrected it and it's working fine.